# How to resolve Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime Crash on EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444 SICK_APPLICATION_DEADA444

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8.1, runtime

I write a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime APP.

I got some crash report from the APP dashboard,
but don't know how to use it or how to debug the app accordingly.
On my local machine I can not reproduce the crash.
I do not find the dump file.

This is an excerpt of the crash report `failures-export_9NBLGGH3THQ9_20150713_20150812.tsv`:

```
9NBLGGH3THQ9 
    2015-08-01 
    ba34d7f4-498c-fcd4-e012-7d4bf26a763e
    EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_Caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState_=_Active. 
    caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState_=_Active.  
    d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2_1.0.0.0_neutral__pbtddhgrx95qt 1.0.0.0 d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2 
    Windows Phone 8.1  
    CN    
    Crash 2 2

9NBLGGH3THQ9 
    2015-08-05 
    957fe591-0d8e-1c05-9688-4dfde547f312 
    MISSING_DUMP_EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState_=_Active. 
    caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState_=_Active.  
    d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2_1.0.0.0_neutral__pbtddhgrx95qt 1.0.0.0 d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2 
    Windows Phone 8.1  
    CN    
    Crash .53 .04

9NBLGGH3THQ9 
    2015-08-03 
    47592457-662a-a475-a240-3592e51565b7 
    SICK_APPLICATION_DEADA444_Caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState_=_Active. 
    caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState_=_Active.  
    d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2_1.0.0.0_neutral__pbtddhgrx95qt 1.0.0.0 d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2 
    Windows Phone 8.1  
    CN    
    Crash 1 1

9NBLGGH3THQ9 
    2015-07-31 
    3f1b4775-4290-03e0-e009-8536c76ad412 
    EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_WATSON_IN_PROGRESS_DEADA444_Caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Quiesce_Hang 
    caixin.exe!{6A2A0B5A-E7E8-4748-A1AB-9B820BE11753}_Quiesce_Hang  
    d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2_1.0.0.0_neutral__pbtddhgrx95qt 1.0.0.0 d302bc2d.49868ff9ecff2   
    CN    
    Crash 1 1

9NBLGGH3THQ9 
    2015-08-12 
    bfc2c682-3af4-587b-7417-9a327af53fd5 
    STOWED_EXCEPTION_Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException_80131500_Newtonsoft.Json.ni.DLL!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue 
    newtonsoft_json_ni!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue  1.0.0.0  
    Windows Phone 8.1  
    CN    
    Crash 1 1
```

Comment: Where you ever able to fix this crash? I'm facing this problem as well.

Comment: Getting EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444 crashes on 8.1. No answers anywhere. Windows Phone is pain in the trunk((

Answer (score 1):

I found an [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acc039ab-0163-4e40-90f7-4dd28135fe2e/wp81c-emwatchdogtimeoutdeada444?forum=wpsubmit) where after a lot of aggravation, a user found that by migrating the app to Win10 UWP the error was suddenly resolved: